# How to change icon cursor of Textfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield

How to change the icon cursor of `Textfield` in `Flutter`?

[image: change_icon_cursor]

(This image is screen shoot on `Android`)

I want to change the icon or change colour of the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the ***handler*** selector, not the ***cursor***, right?

Yo can apply that change using `textSelectionHandleColor` in the root of your app using ThemeData.

I don't think it is possible for individual `TextField`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          textSelectionColor: Colors.yellow,
          textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red)
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried use `textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red` and It's work.

Answer (score 4):

`textSelectionHandleColor` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
Use `TextSelectionThemeData.selectionHandleColor` instead.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          ...
          textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(selectionHandleColor: Colors.black),
          ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ThemeData(
  textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
    cursorColor: pink,
    selectionHandleColor: pink,
    selectionColor: pink
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
  cursorColor: Colors.pink,
)
```

Comment: I tried it on `Android`, but Icon cursor can't change colour.